# Stop users from accessing guest pages after login in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

Is there any way to stop the users from accessing guest pages after they've logged in? I tried using the guest middleware bt nothing happens. I have two sets of guards: RESTAURANT and CUSTOMERS. Once the customer has logged in I don't want them to access the guest pages before log out.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')
        ->name('home'); // This is a guest page
});
```

My customer pages are protected with a customer guard as well.

```php
Route::name('customer.')->middleware(['auth:customer', 'verified'])
    ->group(function () {
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\CustomerLoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

First, I logged in with the customer guard. After then when I type  '/home', the home page is loading. I want to stop logged in users from accessing the guest pages.

Answer (score 1):

Create a middleware and perform following code in it.

```
if (Auth::user()){
// if user HAS authenticated already,
// redirect him to somewhere or die(),
// or any other appropriate action
}
```

Apply middleware on route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest','middlewareName']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')
        ->name('home'); // This is a guest page
});
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `Auth::user()` check on a Guest page:

```
if (Auth::user()){
// if user HAS authenticated already,
// redirect him to somewhere or die(),
// or any other appropriate action
}
```